# Passing Laravel form data to MySQL database, routing or form action issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, forms, routes

I'm trying to pass form data to a controller function and I believe I'm either doing something wrong with the form action or with the routing. Below you can see my form, routes and controller function.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('registreer.store') }}" class="regForm">
      @csrf
      ...
```

---

```
Route::get('/', [RegistreersController::class, 'index']);
Route::post('/', [RegistreersController::class, 'store'])->name('registreer.store');
```

---

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return 123;
}
```

This is a single page application for people to register for an event. I'm trying to save the form data into a mysql database, but when I submit the form, the data doesn't reach the controller since it doesn't return "123". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**SOLUTION:** I found the solution, I simply had to change `action=` to `url=`
I've posted the solution in the comments as well, thanks to everyone who tried to help, much appreciated!

Comment: please show your completely .blade.php codes

Comment: what does it show in dev console?

Comment: this can be a lot of things. we need to know the names of all the files involved and the full code of the blade. are you even sure your controller file has the correct name? or the route is in the proper place? too few info given for us to properly help.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what happens when you submit the form?

Comment: Finally fixed it and posted the solution, thanks to everyone who helped so far, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To all future readers, I simply had to change the `action=` to `url=` in my form tag. After this my data finally went through to my controller.

As many of the comments suggest it could have been many things, such as the name of files, etc, so I should have included more information for the people trying to help but my brain was fried after trying for so many hours.

I'm glad this issue is finally fixed, if you're searching for an answer to a similar issue then don't give up!

Thanks to everyone who tried to help, much appreciated!